# How to download github traffic insight data?

Tags: api, github

GitHub only stores 14 days of data.
Thus I need to download it.
Is there any way to download traffic data as csv or json?

Comment: Similar question: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60915/track-traffic-to-github-repo-longer-than-14-days

Answer (score 2):

You can using the github api. Look for traffic in the [metrics](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/metrics#traffic) section .